# Why I have a (error does not implement interface member) silverlight

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, interface, partial

PagesCollection.ViewModel.PagePictureCommands.cs

```
namespace PagesCollection.ViewModel
{
    public partial class PagePicturesViewModel : IPropertieCommands
    {
        private ICommand deleteAlbum;
        public ICommand _CreateAlbum
        {
            get
            {
                if (createAlbum == null)
                    createAlbum = new Model.DelegateCommand(CreateAlbum, CanAdd);
                return createAlbum;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PagesCollection.ViewModel.PagePicturesViewModel.cs

```
namespace PagesCollection.ViewModel
{
    public partial class PagePicturesViewModel : IPictureMethods
    {
        public void CreateAlbum(object param)
        {...}
    }
}
```

I have one 2 interfaces and one class which divided on 2.Each one half of class has implemented some of those interfaces.But I have a very strange error.
('PagesCollection.ViewModel.PagePicturesViewModel' does not implement interface member 'PagesCollection.Model.IPropertieCommands._CreateAlbum.set')
Can u help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is it you don't understand, because the error message seems pretty descriptive:

> PagesCollection.ViewModel.PagePicturesViewModel' does not implement
>   interface member
>   'PagesCollection.Model.IPropertieCommands._CreateAlbum.set

I suspect that the interface looks like:

```
public interface IPropertieCommands
{
   ICommand _CreateAlbum { get; set; }
}
```

Which defines that you must have a setter on that property!

So just add a setter in your implementation:

```
public ICommand _CreateAlbum
{
    get
    {
        if (createAlbum == null)
            createAlbum = new Model.DelegateCommand(CreateAlbum, CanAdd);
        return createAlbum;
    }
    set
    {
        createdAlbum = value; // or something else sensible!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `IPropertieCommands` interface requires that the `_CreateAlbum` property has a setter - but you've only implemented a getter.

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface IPropertieCommands
{
   ICommand _CreateAlbum { get;}
}
```

If you don't want this property to have a setter (readonly), you can have your interface code like above.